# 'stream-array' readable is not async iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, async-await

I'm have an array which I wish to convert into a readable stream. For that I'm using `stream-array` NPM module.

When I try to itarate through the stream using node.js 10 async-iterators

```
const streamify = require('stream-array');
const readable = streamify(list);
for await (let chunk of readable) {
  ...
}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: readable is not async iterable
```

However with regular `fs` streams it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`stream-array` uses an old version of the `readable-stream` library, which seems to be outdated and does not include the iterable symbol.

Try `scramjet.fromArray` in [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet). It should fit your needs exactly.